# Solve linear equation with Maps

Tags: c++, recursion, maps

I have almost completed the coding to solve simple linear equation set. Just seem to missing something in the recursive call with Maps causing issue.

Here is the problem statement to solve, example:

```
X = Y + 2
Y = Z + R + 1
R = 2 +       3
Z = 1
```

Given: LHS would be just variable names. RHS would have only variables, unsigned int and '+' operator. Solve for all unknowns.

Solution that I get with my code:

```
X = 2
Y = 1
R = 5
Z = 1
```

My code :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
map<string, string> mymap;

// Method to Parse a given expression based on given arg delimiter
// ret: vector of parsed expression
vector<string> parse_expr(string n, char  *delims)
{
    vector<string> v;
    string cleanline;
    char* char_line = (char*)n.c_str(); // Non-const cast required.

    char* token = NULL;
    char* context = NULL;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    token = strtok_s(char_line, delims, &context);

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        cleanline += token;
        cleanline += ' ';
        v.push_back(token);
        token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
    }
    return v;
}

//Method to find sum for a given vector
//retype: string 
//ret: sum of given vector
string find_VctrSum(string key, vector<string> v)
{
    int sum = 0;
    string val;
    vector<string>::iterator i;
    for (i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
    {
        val = *i;
        //cout << "val is :" << val << endl;
        sum += stoi(val);
    }
    return to_string(sum);
}

//Method to check if arg is integer or string
// ret: True if int
bool isNumber(string x) {
    regex e("^-?\\d+");
    if (regex_match(x, e)) return true;
    else return false;
}


//Recursive call to evaluate the set of expressions
string evaluate_eq(string key)
{
    string expr, var;
    vector<string> items;
    vector<string>::iterator i;

    auto temp = mymap.find(key);
    if (temp != mymap.end())  // check temp is pointing to underneath element of a map
    {
        //fetch lhs
        var = temp->first;
        //fetch rhs
        expr = temp->second;
    }

    // remove whitespaces
    expr.erase(remove_if(expr.begin(), expr.end(), isspace), expr.end());

    //Parse RHS by '+' sign
    items = parse_expr(expr, "+");
    for (i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); i++)
    {
        //cout << (*i) << endl;

        if (isNumber(*i) == true)
        {
            //pass- do nothiing
        }
        else
        {
            //recursive call to evaluate unknown
            string c = evaluate_eq(*i);
            //now update the map and Find Sum vector
            mymap[key] = c;
            *i = c;
        }
    }
    //find sum 
    return find_VctrSum(key, items);
}



//main to parse input from text file and evaluate
int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("equation.txt");
    vector<string> v;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            v.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    //Create a map with key:variable and value: expression to solve
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> token;
        token = parse_expr(v[i], "=");
        mymap.insert(pair<string, string>(token[0], token[1]));
    }

    cout << "Equation sets given:" << endl;
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
    }

    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
    {
        //Also update the map
        mymap[it->first] = evaluate_eq(it->first);
    }

    cout << "Equation sets solved:" << endl;
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
    }

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
}
```

Logic is to call recursively for any unknown (string) if found while resolving  a given expression and update the map with values. On debugging, I could see that my recursive call fails at below, but I see "mymap" is being updated. Not sure why.

```
if (temp != mymap.end())
```

Any help in identifying the issue or any logical lapse would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The program invokes undefined behavior due to you attempting to change the returned contents of `n.c_str()` during the `strtok_s` call.

Comment: see return status of map. It return map.end() if value not found in map.

Comment: `// Non-const cast required.` -No.  [strtok is destructive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) -- Read the fine print.  Thus you cannot use the return value of `c_str()` since it is `const`.

Comment: Also, how about 1 test data that demonstrates the issue.  You should have cut out the input routines and plugged in that one piece of test data that duplicates the problem into the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, I would try the fix you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing couple of logic, my code works correctly.

1. In main()

While, creating the input map create by striping whitespace

```
//Create a map with key:variable and value: expression to solve
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> token;
        token = parse_expr(v[i], "=");
        //Strip whitespaces
        token[0].erase(remove_if(token[0].begin(), token[0].end(), isspace), token[0].end());
        token[1].erase(remove_if(token[1].begin(), token[1].end(), isspace), token[1].end());

        mymap.insert(pair<string, string>(token[0], token[1]));
    }
```

This eliminate my issue of finding key in the map -

```
if (temp != mymap.end())
```

2. Updated my find_VctrSum to update the map here, unlike my earlier attempt to update in evaluate_eq().

---

```
//Method to find sum for a given vector
//retype: string 
//ret: sum of given vector
string find_VctrSum(string key, vector<string> v)
{
    int sum = 0;
    string val;
    vector<string>::iterator i;
    for (i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
    {
        val = *i;
        sum += stoi(val);
    }
    //Update the Map
```

> mymap[key] = to_string(sum);

```
    return to_string(sum);

}
```

Here is the complete working code -

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
map<string, string> mymap;

// Method to Parse a given expression based on given arg delimiter
// ret: vector of parsed expression
vector<string> parse_expr(string n, char  *delims)
{
    vector<string> v;
    string cleanline;
    char* char_line = (char*)n.c_str(); // Non-const cast required.

    char* token = NULL;
    char* context = NULL;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    token = strtok_s(char_line, delims, &context);

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        cleanline += token;
        cleanline += ' ';
        v.push_back(token);
        token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
    }
    return v;
}

//Method to find sum for a given vector
//retype: string 
//ret: sum of given vector
string find_VctrSum(string key, vector<string> v)
{
    int sum = 0;
    string val;
    vector<string>::iterator i;
    for (i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
    {
        val = *i;
        sum += stoi(val);
    }
    //Update the Map
    mymap[key] = to_string(sum);
    return to_string(sum);

}

//Method to check if arg is integer or string
// ret: True if int
bool isNumber(string x) {
    regex e("^-?\\d+");
    if (regex_match(x, e)) return true;
    else return false;
}


//Recursive call to evaluate the set of expressions
string evaluate_eq(string key)
{
    string expr, var;
    vector<string> items;
    vector<string>::iterator i;
    string currentkey = key;
    auto temp = mymap.find(key);
    if (temp != mymap.end())  // check temp is pointing to underneath element of a map
    {
        //fetch lhs
        var = key;
        //fetch rhs
        expr = temp->second;
    }
    // remove whitespaces
    expr.erase(remove_if(expr.begin(), expr.end(), isspace), expr.end());
    //Parse RHS by '+' sign
    items = parse_expr(expr, "+");
    for (i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); i++)
    {
        if (isNumber(*i) == true)
        {
            //pass- do nothiing
        }
        else
        {
            //recursive call to evaluate unknown
            string c = evaluate_eq(*i);
            //update the temp vector
            *i = c;
        }
    }
    //find sum 
    return find_VctrSum(key, items);
}


//main to parse input from text file and evaluate
int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("equation.txt");
    vector<string> v;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            v.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    //Create a map with key:variable and value: expression to solve
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> token;
        token = parse_expr(v[i], "=");
        //Strip whitespaces
        token[0].erase(remove_if(token[0].begin(), token[0].end(), isspace), token[0].end());
        token[1].erase(remove_if(token[1].begin(), token[1].end(), isspace), token[1].end());

        mymap.insert(pair<string, string>(token[0], token[1]));
    }
    cout << "Equation sets given:" << endl;
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

    }

    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
    {
        //Also update the map
        mymap[it->first] = evaluate_eq(it->first);
    }

    cout << "Equation sets solved:" << endl;
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

    }


    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
}
```